# Azure Blob storage, CDN and cache expiring

Tags: caching, blob, cdn, azure-storage

We're using Azure CDN, but we've stumbled upon a problem. Before, content could not be updated. But we added the option for our users to crop their picture, which changes the thumbnails. See, the image is not being created as new, instead we just update the stream of the blob.

There doesn't seem to be any method to clear the cache, update any headers or anything else.

Is the only answer here to make a new blob and delete the old?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDN would still cache the content, unless the cache-expiry passes, or the file name changes.

CDN is best for static content with a high cache hit ratio.

Using CDN for dynamic content is not recommended, because it causes the user to wait for a double hop from storage to cdn and from cdn to user.

You also pay twice the bandwidth on the initial load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only workaround right now is to pass a dummy parameter in the request from the client to force download the file every time.

http://resourceurl?dummy=dummyval